# GitHub pages のsourceの保存について

Tags: github, github-pages

エンジニアでもなければgithubもよくわかっていない者です。

https://developers.line.biz/ja/docs/line-things/create-starter-liff-app/
↑にしたがって、line thingsのエンドポイントを設定しようとしています。↑の例では、エンドポイントにgithub pagesを利用するそうで、それに倣ってすすめています。

マニュアルどおり、github pagesのsourceをmaster branchにして、自分のサイトとしてpublishしたいのですが、source項目のmaster branchの横に「SAVE」ボタンがありません。

マニュアルでは「SAVE」ボタンがあるのですが、何か自分の設定が間違っているのでしょうか。
それとも、github pagesの仕様が変わったのでしょうか。

どなたか教えて頂けますと幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @cubick♦ お礼が遅れ申し訳ありません。ありがとうございました。大変助かりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

恐らく仕様が変更になったのか、`Save`ボタンは表示されませんがブランチをプルダウンから選択すると即座に変更が反映され、ページヘッダの黒い帯の下辺りに "GitHub Pages source saved." というメッセージが表示されるはずです。